# Separating names and percentages from a cell with variable amounts of both

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for a way to cut and paste all names and a percentages from a cell into a blank cell in the row below before moving onto the next cell. The number of names and percentages will differ for each row however they will always be formatted the same way.

E.g. Tom Walton (75%); Josh Hargreaves(25%); James Smith (42%); Graham Johnson (56%)

I want to do this for each row in a column.

Screenshot before.

[image]

The desired output.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Sub Parse()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim LR1 As Long, LR2 As Long, i As Long, x As Long, Arr

LR1 = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LR1
    Arr = Split(ws.Range("B" & i), "; ")

    For x = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
        LR2 = ws.Range("E" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
        ws.Range("E" & LR2) = Arr(x)
        ws.Range("D" & LR2).Value = ws.Range("A" & i).Value
    Next x
Next i

End Sub
```

---

*Example of input/out of arbitrary rankings below*

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this! Helpful but quite right, I want it to insert it onto new row.

Comment: Well, the hard part is done for you. This is not a code writing service - you should attempt to solve the issue.

Comment: No, this was very helpful thanks. Think I can make this work :)